# Segmentation fault when copying a portion of an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, copying

I have a function here that copies a portion of an array (first to last) to a new array.  When I ran the code, I ended up getting seg fault.  I know that seg faults happen when I don't allocate enough space to the array or when I try to access memory that hasn't been allocated.  But for my len, I already set it as last-first+1 which should be enough to encompass the portion of the array that I want to copy.  But why does it still give me seg fault? Or am I missing something?

Here is the struct for my code I've done:

```
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

Here's the function to copy the portion of the array to a new one:

```
intarr_t* intarr_copy_subarray( intarr_t* ia, 
                unsigned int first, 
                unsigned int last )
{
    unsigned int len = last-first+1;
    intarr_t* newia = malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));
    assert (newia);
    newia->data = malloc(sizeof(int)*len);
    assert (newia->data);
    newia->len = len;
    if (newia == 0 || ia == NULL || last < first)
    { 
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int x = first; x <= last; x++)
        {
            memcpy (newia->data[x], ia->data[x], (len*sizeof(int)));
        }
        return newia;
    }
    free (newia);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `assert(newia);` `assert (newia->data);` That's bad. Only use `assert` for detecting logic errors, not perfectly normal conditions. (If you do, you'll have found at least one reason for a segmentation-fault.) Also, you have a memory-leak (in two of three cases) if `return NULL;` is executed.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, it was mentioned earlier.  I changed it to check if ia == NULL and last < first first before I allocated any memory and then if the condition above IS null then i set it to return NULL and free (ia).  Is that a good approach to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these statements

```
    for (int x = first; x <= last; x++)
    {
        memcpy (newia->data[x], ia->data[x], (len*sizeof(int)));
    }
```

to

```
memcpy ( newia->data, ia->data + first, len * sizeof( int ) );
```

or to

```
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        newia->data[i] = ia->data[i + first];
    }
```

Also this condition

```
if (newia == 0 || ia == NULL || last < first)
{ 
    return NULL;
}
```

is erroneous. You have to free allocated memory in this block in case either ia is equal to NULL or last < first.

You should check these conditions before allocating memory.

Comment: Oh is the for loop not needed? I thought its needed to loop through the array from indices first to last to copy the elements in those indices.

Comment: @John Claser Either use memcpy or loop as I showed.

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem with the memcpy statement which you have in the for loop. Kindly note that when you are giving newia->data[x] it is getting converting to the integer value at that particular pointer.

So for example data is pointing to an integer variable with value like newia->data[x] = 2 and second one as to another integer variable ia->data[x] = 3 then your memcpy becomes

memcpy(2, 3, len*sizeof(int) );

So effectively you are ending up copying data from address 3 to address 2 for which both are not allocated by you.

You need to follow the way suggested by Vlad from Moscow.